# How to print the "original name" of an input

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to do a comparison of multiple numbers and print out the result in a string type.
Here's a simplified ver.

```
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()
Com = [a, b, c]

print (min(Com) + " is the smallest, the value is %s" %min(Com))
```

For example, when I input 1,2,3 to a,b,c
the output will be

```
"1 is the smallest, the value is 1"
```

but what I really want is

```
"a is the smallest, the value is 1"
```

is there any func. I can use to find out the original name of 1, which is a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your best bet is to use a dictionary, e.g., :

```py
a = input()
b = input()
c = input()

# store the input in a dictionary with values representing the variable names
Com = {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}

minCom = min(Com.keys())
minComName = Com[minCom]

print(minComName + " is the smallest, the value is %s" % minCom)
```

Comment: Should we still consider the conversion to ```int(input())``` first?  Otherwise, this will not work - given ```a = 11,  b = 2, c = 9``` it will yield ```11``` as the minimum number!  OP needs to clear on this!!

Comment: I expect having the conversion to `int`s should be there, but I'll let the OP comment on whether that's what they want.